# GROUP_CONCAT irregardless of filter

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime, aggregate-functions

I have a sample table named *attendance*

```
+------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+
| id   | employee_id  | date         | total_work  | is_regular_holiday |
+------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 1    | e10991       |  11-01-2020  | 28800       | 1                  |
+------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2    | e10991       |  11-02-2020  | 28800       | 0                  |
+------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 3    | e10992       |  11-01-2020  | 28800       | 1                  |
+------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 4    | e10992       |  11-02-2020  | 28800       | 0                  |
+------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 5    | e10993       |  11-02-2020  | 28800       | 0                  |
+------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

Now I have a query

```
select 
  employee_id, 
  sum(total_work) as `total_working_hours`
from attendance
group by employee_id;
```

And this query works

Now I want to get all the sum of **total_work** (irregardless if is_regular_holiday = 1 or not), with holidays worked (if is_regular_holiday = 1) concatenated to a string result,

I tried to query using the one below

```
select 
  employee_id, 
  sum(total_work) as `total_working_hours`, 
  group_concat(select date from attendance_2 where is_holiday = 1) as holidays_worked  
from attendance
group by employee_id;
```

And it returns a syntax error

Is there any way I'm missing in the query or what can be done to attain the group_concat holidays_worked?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Consider a `case` expression within `group_concat()`:

```
select 
    employee_id, 
    sum(total_work) as total_working_hours, 
    group_concat(case when is_regular_holiday then date end order by date) as holidays_worked  
from attendance
group by employee_id;
```

Comment: I got a question though how'd group_concat() filtered individual date? 
Is it because it's already grouped by employee_id?

Comment: group_concat is an aggregation function, like count or sum.  what's inside it is evaluated for each row before grouping.

Comment: @Reyn: yes. `group_concat()` is an aggregate functions, it processes all rows in the group (ie rows that have the same `employee_id`).